# not able to get h1 element and p tag on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have looked up various solution to put an h2 and p tag on the same line but none of them seem to work.  I have tried using display: inline;  but it just going to the next line.  Below is my code in `html` and `css` code:

```css
.NativeName {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div className="NativeName">
  <h2>Native Name:</h2>
  <p>{country.nativeName}</p>
  <h2>Population:</h2>
  <p>{country.population}</p>
  <h2>Region:</h2>
  <p>{country.region}</p>
  <h2>Sub Region:</h2>
  <p> {country.subregion}</p>
  <h2>Capital:</h2>
  <p> {country.capital}</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is being ignored because the attribute name should be `class` rather than `className`.

Comment: The project is done in React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid using a wrapper for each `<h2><p>` line, you can use the `<br>` tag and set the `dispay` of each `<h2>` and `<p>` to `inline-block`:

```css
.NativeName {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

h2,
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div className="NativeName">
  <h2>Native Name:</h2>
  <p>{country.nativeName}</p>
  <br>
  <h2>Population:</h2>
  <p>{country.population}</p>
  <br>
  <h2>Region:</h2>
  <p>{country.region}</p>
  <br>
  <h2>Sub Region:</h2>
  <p> {country.subregion}</p>
  <br>
  <h2>Capital:</h2>
  <p> {country.capital}</p>
</div>
```

But I really recommend you to wrapp them in a `div` using `display: flex`:

```css
.NativeName {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div className="NativeName">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Native Name:</h2>
    <p>{country.nativeName}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Population:</h2>
    <p>{country.population}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Population:</h2>
    <p>{country.population}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Region:</h2>
    <p>{country.region}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Sub Region:</h2>
    <p> {country.subregion}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Capital:</h2>
    <p> {country.capital}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add styling to the elements inside the `.NativeName` div. By default, a `h2` and `p` element are block. That means they will take the full width. To not do that, you need to set `display: inline-block` explicit.

```css
.NativeName {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

h2,
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div className="NativeName">
  <h2>Native Name:</h2>
  <p>Some random name</p>
</div>
```

**Edit** 
What would be even better is to make use of HTML's definition list ([read about it at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)), since that would make it semantically more correct.

```css
.NativeName {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

dt,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div class="NativeName">
    <dt>Native Name:</dt>
    <dd>Some random name</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="NativeName">
    <dt>Code Name:</dt>
    <dd>Some random code</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```